# How to divide string in perl for 2 parts

Tags: string, perl, divide

so I need to divide my string in perl for 2 parts. For example I have:

```
$string = "../dira/dirb/*.txt"
```

And I want to divide it on:

```
$stringA = "../dira/dirb"
$stringB = "*.txt"
```

But if I have:

```
$string = "dira/dirb/dirc/.../dirn/test.pl";
```

I want to divie it on:

```
$stringA = "dira/dirb/dirc/.../dirn"
$stringB = "test.pl"
```

Somebody have idea how can I do it? I tried to do something like:

```
$howmany++ while $string =~ m/\//g;
```

So I know how many slashes I have. But I have no idea what I can do more with this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
$string =~ m|^(.*)/(.*)$|;
($stringA,$stringB) = ($1,$2);
print "stringA = $stringA\n";
print "stringB = $stringB\n";
```

**= edit: =**

restrict to certain values of `stringB`:

```
if($string =~ m|^(.*)/(.*\.pl)$|) {
    ($stringA,$stringB) = ($1,$2);
    print "stringA = $stringA\n";
    print "stringB = $stringB\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you have maybe idea how can I use as stringB for example "*.pl"?

Comment: I mean, that I want to print * symbol as StringB :P Because when I use for example: "perl lab2.pl ./e.pl" it works ok and show me "." as stringA and "e.pl" as stringB. But when I use "perl lab2.pl ./*.pl" it shows me "." as stringA and "lab2.pl" as stringB, and I want to have "*.pl" as stringB.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Path::Tiny;

for my $path (qw( ../dira/dirb/*.txt
                  dira/dirb/dirc/.../dirn/test.pl
             )) {
    my $path_o = 'Path::Tiny'->new($path);
    my $basename = $path_o->basename;
    my $dirname = $path_o->dirname;
    $dirname =~ s=/$==;               # Remove the trailing slash.
    say $basename, ' ', $dirname;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I forget to say that I can't use anything like "use XXX::YYY" :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) functions to parse file paths:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $string = "../dira/dirb/*.txt";
my $stringA = dirname($string);
my $stringB = basename($string);

printf "String A: %-25sString B: %s\n", $stringA, $stringB;

$string = "dira/dirb/dirc/.../dirn/test.pl";
$stringA = dirname($string);
$stringB = basename($string);

printf "String A: %-25sString B: %s\n", $stringA, $stringB;
```